# C# MySQL Change Credentials or Logout on the fly

Tags: c#, mysql, database, security

I am currently developing a C# WPF application. It is only used by a small amount of people/devices.
To make things easier I decided to talk directly to the MySQL db.

Now I wanted to be able to switch the current User / db Credentials with the click of a button, or be able to implement a logout feature.

I just currently tried this:

```
    public DBConnect()
    {
        Initialize(null, null);
    }


    private void Initialize(string uid, string password)
    {
        string connectionstring;
        connectionstring = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring);
    }

    public void setCredentials(string uid, string password)
    {
        Initialize(uid, password);
    }

    public void destroyCredentialsAndConnection()
    {
        connection = null;
    }
```

But apparently while Debugging I found out, that the old connection string is still cached statically by the MySQLConnection Class in the background.

Currently it does look like my approach is working, but I'm actually worried about the security of that implementation to list a few concerns:

1. memory dumps (usage of strings for passwords that can not be encrypted and may not be removed for quite some time by the garbage collector)
2. memory dumps (the fact that the connection string is being cached even after a "logout")
3. network traffic sniffing (is the connection between the database and my C# application encrypted)?
4. physical access to the server (is the MySQL database stored encrypted on the harddrive)?

Is there any better (more secure) way to switch credentials or to completely log the user out?

I did not really find any similar attempts here or anywhere else while doing research.

And if I would try to develop a php backend would that be safer without much experience? And could I still use my audit tables that I have created based on MySQL Triggers?

Comment: It is only the connection string which isn't destroed and you could clear it. but much more wirk is it to keep the connection only as local variable where you use transfer parameter and before you leave finction or sub you use the garbage collector. I would be much more cincerned, if the connection isn't encryted, because every packet sniffer could read the credentials.

Comment: Is the connection between the C# application (using the MySQL class) and the MySQL Server not encrypted? I thought that they would use a SSL encryption by default? If that is not the case, the whole situation is even worse. And is it really just the string itself? I read somewhere here on stackoverflow that the MySQL Class is caching connections in general (e.g. not even always closing connections) to allow a better performance for upcoming queries? Therefore I would have to delete those cached too, right?

Comment: I don't know your connection stirng, but by default it isn't encrypted, but with some configuration it only allows ssl encrypted connections.. Oh that with connections you have to read yourself, that is much more compölicated with threadin https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/client-connections.html

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding what you are asking correctly, you could try making a method to build the connection string based on user input, and inject the user's credentials into the connection string each time the method is called.

```
static SqlConnection Connection()
{
   string UserName = UserNameField.Text;
   string Password = PasswordField.Text;

   SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConection("Server=ServerName,Port;Initial Catalog=Catalog;User Id=" + UserName + ";Password=" + Password + ";");
   return Connection;
}
```

Comment: I think I expressed myself indistinctly in my question - sorry. I actually have a similar function. I'm just a little unsure about security. When debugging, I found that e.g. the connection string is statically stored by the MySQLConnection class (and maybe even more). My implementation works so far. I am only very unsure whether in my current implementation it would still be technically possible to get the access data after logging out etc. Therefore I am looking for a really secure way to connect to the database including logging out and changing users.

Comment: My apologies for misunderstanding the question.

Comment: No problem at all. It's my fault. I just expressed myself very vaguely. In the meantime I've also tried to specify my question somehow.